# Formatting numbers from 1000 to 10.00

Tags: php, numbers, format

I'll like to format 1000 to 10.00
The PHP number_format function does not seem to be working for this.

I have tried:

```
$amount2 = number_format("$cost",2,"",",");
echo "$cost";
```

Any ideas? Is there a way I can manupulate number_format to display the results (i.e just inserting a decimal before the last two digits?

Answer (score 5):

Number format will change the "." to a "," but you telling it to format ONE THOUSAND.

```
$cost=1000;
echo number_format($cost,2,'.',',');
//1,000.00
```

What you want is simply:

```
$cost=1000;
 echo number_format($cost/100,2,'.',',');
//10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to `number_format` should be the character you want to use as a decimal point. Why are you passing an empty string? And why are you placing your number (`$cost`) inside a string?

Try this: `echo number_format($cost,2,'.',',');`

**EDIT:** Perhaps I misunderstood your question — if you want the number 1000 to be displayed as 10.00, just divide `$cost` by 100 before calling `number_format()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this legit for you ?

```
<?php
$cost=1000;
echo substr($cost, 0, 2) . "." . substr($cost, 2);//10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

1000 and 10.00 are totally different numbers (in values). Divide by 100, then format it properly:

```
$cost = 1000 ;
$cost /= 100 ;

$amount2 = number_format($cost,2,".","");
echo $amount2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$stringA= 1000;
$length=strlen($stringA);
$temp1=substr($stringA,0,$length-2);
$temp2=substr($stringA,$length-2,$length);
echo $temp1.".".$temp2;     // Displays  10.00
```