# Format 1000 to 10.00 with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for on how to format:

`1000` to `10.00`
`8900` to `89.00`
`10000` to `100.00`
etc.

Meaning simply get the number and add a dot (.) 2 decimals before its end. I found this PHP way of doing it [Formatting numbers from 1000 to 10.00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445746/formatting-numbers-from-1000-to-10-00) , but cannot get a way to it with jQuery. Would really appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide the number by 100 then use `toFixed(2)`, like this:

```js
function format(num) {
  return (num / 100).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(format(1000))
console.log(format(8900))
console.log(format(10000))
```

Comment: Thank u so much bro! this help me for Gumroad API which they have no formatted prices for ex 2900 as a $29.00 then with your solution I've added dollar sign to make a price format function:
return '$' + (num / 100).toFixed(2);